# Loop through and read json data elements in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am unable to read data element properties from the given json data.

```
{
    "Parent": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "data": {
                "54": {
                    "id": 54,
                    "type": "TEXTBOX"
                },
                "55": {
                    "id": 55,
                    "type": "RADIO"
                },
                "57": {
                    "id": 57,
                    "type": "MENU"
                },
                "58": {
                    "id": 58,
                    "type": "RADIO"
                },
                "38": {
                    "id": 38,
                    "type": "RADIO"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If i apply foreach to data element i am getting key values like 54,54..
But i want read type value from the each data element.
Can any one suggest me how to read type value from the data element in Powershell.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output? Define *read type value*.

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the `foreach` statement that you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = @'
... your data
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
$x.parent.data | Get-Member -MemberType noteproperty | Foreach-Object { 
  $x.parent.data.($_.name).type
}
```

NB. This will come out ordered by the id, so you might want to remove the .type from the end to get the data out with the id included